# View not updating when adding new data from Room database in kotlin and compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

So I am trying to build out a watch app for Android using kotlin, jetpack, and compose with a room database. I can see that the data is being retrieved and my observer is being called and adding data to my mutableList, but the UI isn't updating and I get an empty chart.

I'm still pretty new to kotlin, even newer to compose, and first time I am trying to use room, so this is all a little confusing and I could use a hand please.

I'll omit the dao, repo, and viewmodel code because it's all pretty boilerplate stuff and try to give you the parts of code that would be relevant, but I will gladly add more code samples of what I have if it's needed. Just trying to keep this short.

my view code...

```
@Composable
fun ChartsView(mode: TimeViewModel) {
  val dayFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.US)
  val date = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(6)
  val lastWeek = Date(date.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC))
  var barData = mutableListOf<BarData>()
  model.getFrom(lastWeek.time).observe(LocalLifecycleOwner.current) { times ->
    Log.d("CHARTS", "Loading ${times.size} entries into barData")
    for(time in times) {
      val eventDate = Utils.storageFormatter.parts(time.dateString)!!
      val day = dayFormat.format(eventDate)
      barData.add(BarData(day, time.time.toFloat())
    }
  }

  Column(
    modifier = Modifer.fillMaxSize().padding(start = 18.dp, end = 18.dp),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top
  ) {
    Spacer(Modifier.height(28.dp))
    //...some code to display information
    Log.d("CHARTS", "INSIDE VIEW: $barData")
    Log.d("CAHRTS", "${barData.size}")
    if(barData.isEmpty()) {
      Log.d("CHARTS", "barData.size was 0, adding blank entry")
      barData.add(BarData("?", 0f))
    }
    //...my chart using bar data.
  }
}
```

In case you need it, from the dao it's returning live data....

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM times where timestamp > :timestamp")
fun getFrom(timestamp: Long): LiveData<List<Times>>
```

In the console I can see it's getting the data from the room database and adding the entries, but the count in the view is always 0. Console...

```
D/CHARTS: loading 1 entries into barData
D/CHARTS: INSIDE VIEW: []
D/CHARTS: 0
D/CHARTS: bardata.size was 0, adding a blank entry
```

Based on the first comment I got I changed the code to...

```
val barData = remember {
  mutableStateListOf<BarData>()
}
...
model.getFrom(lastWeekDate.time).observe(LocalLifecycleOwner.current) { times ->
  for(time in times) {
    val eventDate = Utils.storageFormatter.parse(time.dateString)!!
    val day = dayFormat.format(eventDate)
    barData.add(BarData(day, time.time.toFloat())
  }
}
```

However that puts it into an infinite loop where, by the time I hit the stop button on the emulator, I had this in my console...

```
D/CHARTS: INSIDE VIEW: androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList@f4e8df2
D/CHARTS: 229
D/CHARTS: INSIDE VIEW, with Data: androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList@ede5c43
D/CHARTS: 0
D/CHARTS: loading 1 entries into barData
D/CHARTS: INSIDE VIEW: androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList@f4e8df2
D/CHARTS: 230
D/CHARTS: INSIDE VIEW, with Data: androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList@ede5c43
D/CHARTS: 0
D/CHARTS: loading 1 entries into barData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each recomposition you create new instace of list

```
 var barData = mutableListOf<BarData>()
```

first thing you should do is to remember your list and instead of using mutableListOf use SnapshotStateList to trigger recomposition when you add or remove items from the list

`var barData = remember { mutableStateListOf<BarData>() }` will solve the issue.

And to prevent adding new observer on every recomposition which you add new value and trigger another recomposition causing your Composable to recompose use LaunchedEffect to do it only once or use with keys.

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    model.getFrom(lastWeekDate.time).observe(LocalLifecycleOwner.current) { times ->
        for (time in times) {
            val eventDate = Utils.storageFormatter.parse(time.dateString)!!
            val day = dayFormat.format(eventDate)
            barData.add(BarData(day, time.time.toFloat())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do it that way it gets stuck in an infinite loop where it keeps adding entries. I changed it to mutableStateListOf<BarData>() and run the app in a simulator and the console goes nuts and keeps adding items. By the time I stopped it it had logged "D/CHARTS: INSIDE VIEW: androidx..." and D/CHARTS: 230" It had added 230 items to the list and was still going.

Comment: You use it with remember right? And the thing that probably causes infinite recomposition is observing with new observer on each recomposition. You can put it inside a LaunchedEffect to create only one observer and when you add new item to your barData it will cause one recomposition which will update your Column

Comment: Yeah, I'm using remember on it. I updated my original post with the new code that I am using with the mutableStateListOf inside the remember. Do I put the remember in a LaunchedEffect, or do I put the observer in the LaunchedEffect?

Comment: You need to set observer inside LaunchedEffect. In Jetpack Compose you need a State, SnapShotStataList or SnapshotStateMap to trigger recomposition when you set a new value and want specific part of your Composable to be recomposed. However, if you set a value inside observer in each ecomposition it will trigger another recomposition and so on. To prevent that you can set observer inside LaunchedEffect(Unit) for it to be set in composition

Comment: You need mutableStateList of to trigger recomposition when you add new items, you need remember to not create new instance of this list on each recomposition and you need LaunchedEffect to not set new observer on each recomposition

Comment: Awesome thank you sir. I'll try it out and report back